# How to get rid of \n when writing to a file?

Tags: python

So my code is supposed to take words from one file and put quotes around them and write them into a second file. But when writing into the file they appear as such " "apple\n""banana\n""cherry" ". How do I get rid of the \n?

```
import json

idk = open('./words.txt', 'r')
formatted = open('./formattedwords.txt', 'w')

for word in idk:
    formatted.write(json.dumps(word))

idk.close()
```

Comment: How about `formatted.write(json.dumps(word.strip()))`

Comment: @user10987432 Wow that worked. Thank you